# Puppeteer Bright Data proxy returning ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXY or CERT errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, proxy, puppeteer

So I went on Bright Data, made an account, and got my Search Engine Crawler proxy. Here's my scraping function below:

```
async function scrape() {
  try {
    const preparePageForTests = async (page) => {

          const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36';//'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36';

          await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);

          await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
              get: () => false,
            });
          });

          // Pass the Chrome Test.
          await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            // We can mock this in as much depth as we need for the test.
            window.navigator.chrome = {
              app: {
                isInstalled: false,
              },
              webstore: {
                onInstallStageChanged: {},
                onDownloadProgress: {},
              },
              runtime: {
                PlatformOs: {
                  MAC: 'mac',
                  WIN: 'win',
                  ANDROID: 'android',
                  CROS: 'cros',
                  LINUX: 'linux',
                  OPENBSD: 'openbsd',
                },
                PlatformArch: {
                  ARM: 'arm',
                  X86_32: 'x86-32',
                  X86_64: 'x86-64',
                },
                PlatformNaclArch: {
                  ARM: 'arm',
                  X86_32: 'x86-32',
                  X86_64: 'x86-64',
                },
                RequestUpdateCheckStatus: {
                  THROTTLED: 'throttled',
                  NO_UPDATE: 'no_update',
                  UPDATE_AVAILABLE: 'update_available',
                },
                OnInstalledReason: {
                  INSTALL: 'install',
                  UPDATE: 'update',
                  CHROME_UPDATE: 'chrome_update',
                  SHARED_MODULE_UPDATE: 'shared_module_update',
                },
                OnRestartRequiredReason: {
                  APP_UPDATE: 'app_update',
                  OS_UPDATE: 'os_update',
                  PERIODIC: 'periodic',
                },
              }
            };
          });

          await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            const originalQuery = window.navigator.permissions.query;
            return window.navigator.permissions.query = (parameters) => (
              parameters.name === 'notifications' ?
                Promise.resolve({ state: Notification.permission }) :
                originalQuery(parameters)
            );
          });

          await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            // Overwrite the `plugins` property to use a custom getter.
            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'plugins', {
              // This just needs to have `length > 0` for the current test,
              // but we could mock the plugins too if necessary.
              get: () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            });
          });

          await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            // Overwrite the `plugins` property to use a custom getter.
            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'languages', {
              get: () => ['en-US', 'en'],
            });
          });
        }

        //the below is the Search Engine Crawler proxy used from the luminati/bright data sign up. This returns ERR_CERT_INVALID or ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
        const oldProxyUrl = 'http://lum-customer-customerID-zone-zone1:customerPassword@zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225'
        const newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(oldProxyUrl); //if this line is commented out, I get the ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXY

        const browser = await puppeteerExtra.launch({ 
          headless: true, 
          args: [                
            '--no-sandbox', 
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox', 
            `--proxy-server=${newProxyUrl}`
            //If I add 'ignoreHTTPSErrors: true' here then I can bypass the CERT errors but then it seems like I can't navigate the browser anymore to a different page.                     
          ]
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await preparePageForTests(page);

        await page.setViewport({ width: 1440, height: 1080 });

        await page.goto('https://www.google.com/search?q=concerts+near+new+york');   
        
        await page.screenshot({ path: `screenshot.jpeg` });

  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Not sure how to solve this. I believe the error here is with bypassing CERT errors with ignoreHttpsErrors. When I don't use a proxy at all, my analysis function (which essentially takes in the first 'ul' list seen below) works fine but if I use the proxy, it for some reason is giving me the data on the second page.

Any help would be much appreciated!

The 'ul' is nicely formatted and the data is easy to get at:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwiHM.jpg

only a few 'ul' elements are visible and then I get a bunch of stuff I don't want returned. I tried doing a

```
page.$eval(".BXE0fe", element => element.click())
```

but that isn't redirecting the page for some reason:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DTay.png

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the point Yevgeniy made about targeting Google (he's right btw, for Google you need to use their SERP product), if you're requesting through HTTPS you need to have their CA certificate installed and send requests through the Proxy Manager instead of through the Superproxy directly, and none of this would even matter for headless Chromium because of [this unresolved Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=757181).

Comment: My 'oldProxyUrl' is from the Bright Data SERP product. I'm not getting the ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED specified in your link, but rather ERR_CERT_AUTH_INVALID or ERR_CERT_INVALID. There has to be a way...

Answer (score 0):

Bright Data support can definitely help you with this issue - you can contact them through the chat bubble in your control panel or on Skype: luminati.io

This issue depends on which domain you are targeting (Bright Data blocks Google domains, you should use a SERP zone for google)

Comment: @YevgeniyBaranovskiy What exactly do you mean by SERP 'zone'? Does that have anything to do with the 'zone' keyword in the Bright Data proxy? Or do you just mean I need to use 'Search Engine Crawler' (https://brightdata.com/cp/howto)

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the search engine crawler.

Comment: I worked with BrightData yesterday and got a Search Engine Crawler proxy all set up but I am still having some issues--I updated my question to reflect the changes I made to the code and the problem that has arisen. Thanks for your help!